# What is strength of an electromagnet at a distance?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want to levitate a permanent magnet between two electromagnets. My two governing equations are:

$$F = \frac{B^{2}A}{{2\mu_{0}}}\tag{1}$$
$$B = \frac{NI\mu}{L}\tag{2}$$

Where $x$ is the distance from the electromagnet to the permanent magnet.

Given the mass of the magnet and the distance between the magnet and each electromagnet, I can determine the force that each electromagnet must generate to counter the weight of the permanent magnet. However, I'm not sure how to calculate $B$ at said distance. I've heard that magnetic fields decrease as an inverse cube, so **can I model $B$ like this**:

$$B(x) = \frac{NI\mu}{Lx^{3}}$$

That way I can plug the above equation into (1) and solve for the current necessary for levitation at a given distance, mass, number of turns, etc.

Comment: You could do all of that... or... you could do an experiment. If you do, you will quickly find that the magnet will stick to the metal yoke of your electromagnet instead of levitating. If you go with an air coil, then this problem won't occur, but you will find yourself needing such a high current, that the coil will get very hot and will need some sort of cooling. Did you look at the typical levitation setups that are using magnets to produce strong enough fields to levitate another magnet? Those designs use a diamagnetic material or a small electrical current to keep the system stable.

Comment: F is inversely proportional to the cube of the distance. If F is proportional to B^2, then B would be proportional to x^-1.5. I don't know about what constants to use, though.